# How to represent a signal on negative X Axis

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

first I would like to say it is my first time using Matplotlib and Numpy so I will be wrong about what I am talking about and this code is definitely super messy, Thank you.

I have got this signal, and I am trying to get a graph of its Magnitude Spectrum my problem is that I cant seem to represent its negative values, FYI I did not make this code from scratch I got it off a Magnitude Spectrum example and adapted it.
What am I doing wrong?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


np.random.seed(0)

dt = 1  # sampling interval
Fs = 11000  # sampling frequency
t = np.arange(0,1,1/Fs)

s = 20000 * np.cos(2 * np.pi * 5025 * t) + 10000*np.cos(2 * np.pi * 2507 * t -np.pi/2)  # the signal

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(10, 10))


axs[0, 0].set_title("Magnitude Spectrum")
axs[0, 0].set_xlim([-Fs/2, Fs/2])
axs[0, 0].magnitude_spectrum(s, Fs=Fs, color='C1')

axs[0, 1].remove()  # don't display empty ax
axs[1, 0].remove()
axs[1, 1].remove()


fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: why do you expect the *magnitude* spectrum to have negative values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
axs[0, 0].magnitude_spectrum(s, Fs=Fs, color='C1', sides= 'twosided')
```

[Reference](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.magnitude_spectrum.html)